# Python: opencv (cv2) image slicing not working?

Tags: python, opencv, numpy, imread

I've got an image loaded in grayscale via `img = cv2.imread("myimg.jpg", 0)`.

Examining the value of `img` after loading, it's an `ndarray` that looks like this:

```
[[53,53,58,...,62,66,70],
 [52,52,57,...,68,68,90],
 ...,
 [80,80,80,...,91,92,91],
 [81,82,80,...,90,91,93]]
```

Trying to crop out a chunk of it using `cropped = img[top:bottom, left:right]` where `top`, `bottom`, `left` and `right` are all integers.

However, cropped is winding up as an empty `ndarray`.

Why would this be?

Comment: can you give example values for top, bottom, left and right ?

Comment: top=337, left=74, bottom=271, right=140. Now that I'm looking at it, I'm guessing I've got them flipped, haven't I? i.e., top should be less than bottom?

Comment: Yes, see my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to split your array while supplying top = 337 and bottom = 271. Numpy works the other way around. Try to split it like this: `img[bottom:top, left:right]` or just invert the values of `top` and `bottom` so that you have `img[a:b, c:d]` with `a < b` and `c < d`.